# Download actual logs of a graph Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

There is two options in kibana for downloading data of a graph

i.e. formatted and raw data.

But my requirement is to download actual log from which a graph has been build means data without applying any parsing rules.

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to get the raw log files from your server, but you can't get that through Kibana.

Comment: I was trying to write something inside kibana.bundle.js , i just created a button download actual log but couldn't find anyway to achieve this. :(